# What is the method for solving this class of problem?

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

$\frac{dx}{dt} = y$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\partial y - \mu x - x^2$

Find the fixed points and discuss stability.

I'd at least like to know what I should be googling, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Google "steady solution of differential equation", "stability and linearization", "bifurcation diagram".